# How to not resize input image while running Tensorflow SSD's inference

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

From what I can understand from Single Shot Multibox Detector paper, it is a fully convolutional network. As such, it won't require the rescaling which tensorflow is doing (to 300x300) during inference. How can I remove this resizing during inference in tensorflow?

Answer (score -1):

You can configure this in model config file

```
image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
}
```

If you remove `image_resizer` it should work fine. But to answer your question: Why do you want to do remove resizing?
Removing resizing would seriously impact training time and performance. And since your training images and input images are resized by tensorflow model config, model could still 'see' it same, in case you were thinking about information loss. Also, SSD was trained on COCO and for aforementioned reasons of training time and performance, they thought of resizing them.

Though you could try following alternatives than resizing if for some reasons that is not what you want to do.

- Multiple crops. For example AlexNet was originally trained on 5 different crops: center, top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right.
- Random crops. Just take a number of random crops from the image and hope that the Neural Network will not be biased.
- Resize and deform. Resize the image to a fixed size without considering the aspect ratio. This will deform the image contents but preserves but now you are sure that no content is cut.
- Variable-sized Inputs. Do not crop and train the network on variable sized images, using something like Spatial Pyramid Pooling to extract a fixed size feature vector that can be used with fully connected layers.

Comment: Intention was to train and run the inference for the actual size of the image coming in. Wanted to remove the resize part altogether because for my application, I'll be getting image size lesser than 300 most of the times (80% of the time) and running inference by resizing was computationally expensive.

I'll check out the variable-sized input training and inference.

Comment: how is it going of no-resize ssd image input?

Comment: You can not remove image_resizer from the config. The model builder requires an image_resizer_builder. You have to provide an image resizer.